# OpenVPN server dedicated log missing log.conf?

Tags: logging, openvpn

I'm trying to run an OpenVPN server with it's own log, not just writing to the Syslog with everything else. For some reason it looks like you can only set a different log location by using a command argument, either --log or --log-append
When I try to start the service with --log I get the below error:

service openvpn start --log /var/log/openvpn/openvpn-server.log
Starting VPN '/var/log/openvpn/openvpn-server.log': missing /etc/openvpn//var/log/openvpn/openvpn-server.log.conf file

I've not seen anything about a log.conf file in the documentation. Can someone please point me at a working example or at least explain why it's trying to look in the path that it is?

Answer (score 0):

You can't start the OpenVPN service using the `--log` directive. You have to configure it in your `server.conf`, e.g.:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
local nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn

ca /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/server.key
dh /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/dh2048.pem



log-append /var/log/openvpn.log


tun-mtu 1500
txqueuelen 500

server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
client-to-client
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nogroup
cipher AES-256-CBC
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
management 192.168.0.1 3000
```

Or you can start the OpenVPN daemon without systemd or upstart using the binary (usually `/usr/sbin/openvpn`) with your desired parameters, e.g. `--log-append` or `--log` etc.